# "Unknown layer type: net in function" when loading yolov3 using OpenCV's DNN library

Tags: opencv, yolo, darknet

I am attempting to use Yolov3 using OpenCV's (4.0.1) DNN Library on MacOs in C++. I am trying to use `cv::dnn::readNetFromDarknet` to load the yolov3.cfg file but I am getting this error :

```
"(-212:Parsing error) Unknown layer type: net in function
'ReadDarknetFromCfgStream'"
```

I've made sure the yolov3.cfg that is within my project matches up with the one on the web https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov3.cfg which it does. If I change " `[net]` " to something else for example " `[layer]` " then the error will change to :

```
"(-212:Parsing error) Unknown layer type: layer in function
'ReadDarknetFromCfgStream'"
```

Almost as if either the cfg file is wrong or opencv is not reading it correctly.

The start of the config file looks like this :

```
[net]
# Testing
# batch=1
# subdivisions=1
# Training
batch=64
subdivisions=16
width=608
height=608
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.001
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 500200
policy=steps
steps=400000,450000
scales=.1,.1
```

which is where I assume the problem is.

My code for loading the net is :

```
const char * pathStart = gGetRootAppPath();
pathEnd = "/yolo/yolov3.cfg";
std::string modelConfiguration = pathStart + pathEnd;
pathEnd = "/yolo/yolov3.weights";
std::string modelWeights = pathStart + pathEnd;

//set up the neural network
cv::dnn::readNetFromDarknet(modelConfiguration,modelWeights);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try to use absolute path, dont use `const char * pathStart = gGetRootAppPath()`

Comment: thanks @gameon67, I've tried that but I'm still getting the same problem.